# How to differentiate between different Retrofit responses in Authenticators or Interceptors?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a basic `Retrofit` setup for network requests. I have the following `Authenticator` that is added to the chain. It basically tries to refresh access token when authorization error (401) occurs.

```
class TokenAuthenticator(private val api: MyApi) : Authenticator {

    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {

        val retrofitResponse = api.refreshAccessToken("my refresh token here"))
        val refreshResponse= retrofitResponse.blockingGet()

        return if(refreshResponse != null) {
                     response.request().newBuilder()
                        .header(Const.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + refreshResponse.accessToken)
                        .build()
            } else {
                return null
            }

    }
}
```

The problem is my server might return 401 not only for authroization issues but also for some other cases. For example, i might get response with 401 if user phone number already exists in the database. Server returns me `error_code` paramter to differentiate this type of issues:

- `error_code = "token_expired"` -> authoriation issue. shows that access token expired.
- `error_code = "phone_exists"` -> shows phone number entered already exsits in the database.

So, I need to be able to check for this paramter before deciding that error was access token refresh error. How can I do that?

Currently, since I have not been able to check for that paramter, my app thinks that 401 is an authroization issue and continuously trying to refresh the access token even though my access token is not expired.

Comment: you can use valition trough request like if (reuestcode==200){sucess}else if{request==401}{

Answer (score 0):

we had similar issue in our project, it may be a little mess because of hard-coded url but i think it is okey

we check the request's url and if it matched with the refresh token url then we start process of getting new token

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `ErrorInterceptor`?

```
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Response

class ErrorInterceptor: Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain?): Response {

        val originalResponse = chain!!.proceed(chain.request())

        if (shouldLogout(originalResponse)) {
            // your logout logic here

            // send empty response down the chain
            return Response.Builder().build()

        }
        return originalResponse
    }

    private fun shouldLogout(response: Response) : Boolean {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            return false
        }

        // 401 and auth token means that we need to logout
        return (response.code() == 401 &&
                !response.headers().names().contains(AUTH_HEADER_KEY))
    }
}
```